# Generalization of "round robin scheduling" problem

Tags: combinatorics

I've just came up with this question, which is the generalization of the "round robin scheduling" problem, but I think we can't use the polygon method to solve it, so if anyone has any idea, feel free to share it :).
Question: Given positive integers $n$ and $d$ such that $d|n$. A game requires $d$ participants a match is called a **d-game**. A tournament of a d-game is held with $n$ participants. Can we schedule $\binom{n-1}{d-1}$ rounds such that any d participants play against each other exactly once and everyone plays once in every round?

Comment: This question was discussed on stackoverflow, their discussion may be useful. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9260017/algorithm-scheduling-round-robin-tournament-with-multi-teams-game